# How to configure ASP.NET MVC 3 on IIS 6 (Windows 2003 R2)

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deploying ASP.NET MVC to Windows Server 2003](https://serverfault.com/questions/150973/deploying-asp-net-mvc-to-windows-server-2003)

I am getting 403 Directory Listing Denied for the root and 404 for an action that I know should exist.

Background:
I have build and deployed an ASP.NET MVC 2 applcation a long time ago. Later I upgraded it to MVC 3 and it is still working with not configuration changes. Setting it up on a windows 2003 R2 (Standard) initialy was a pain, but after a couple of days(yes, days) struggling it started working.

Now I have to do the same with the same application on a different server (2003 R2 Standard again) on a different network.

- .Net 4 is installed and allowed
- ASP.NET MVC 3 is also installed
- By default IIS is set to use .net 4
- I verify aspnet_isapi.dll used in application extension are from
  version 4.0.30319 .NET asemblies folder.
- I also added the wildcard mapping to aspnet_isapi.dll and unchecked
  verify file exists.
- Under Directory Security in Authentication Methods I have disabled
  anonymos access and enabled Integrated Windows authentication(same as
  the one on the server that it works)
- I have copied the same web.config with the

`<authentication mode="Windows" />`

`<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
</authorization>`

- I have set Read & Execute, List Folder Contents, and Read for the
  Networkservice account(under which the app pool is working). Also I
  have set the same for Network account, IIS_WPG, ASPNET and
  IUSR_MAchineName.
- I do not have an EnableExte‌​nsionlessUrls but even if I create it
  and set it to true or false it does not help.
- I also tried
  http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/22/asp-net-mvc-3-extensionless-urls-on-iis-6.aspx
  and it did not help.

But I kept getting 403 Directory Listing Denied for the root and 404 for an action that I know should exist.

Web Platform installer was then used to re-install and possibly update .net, asp.net etc. I then noticed IIS was reset to default. So I added the wildcard mapping again. No, luck still 403.

I exported configuration files from the working server setup and created new default app pool and new default website using those configurations.

Still I get 403 Directory Listing Denied for the / and 404 for any action I try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another reason to get 404 and 403 is have Global.asax missing, thanks to [Deploying ASP.NET MVC to Windows Server 2003](https://serverfault.com/q/150973/146579) I was also able to fix it.